# Creating a large horizontal table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable

i want to create a horizontal table, which gives an overview over other studies in my field. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum % Text before

\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \centering % Center table
        \begin{table}[h]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Research Studies}}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\
\textbf{Study Category}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    & \textbf{Author}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            & \textbf{Study Title}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & \textbf{Description}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & \textbf{Data}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              & \textbf{Results}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum.
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}
        \captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
\lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error: `Dimension too large.
\width ->\wd \@tempboxa`.

Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Comment: What's with the huge "Lorem Ipsum"? I mean, I doubt it fits in a single cell/column. I deleted most of it, and now it compiles fine. If you want, you can set the column to have a fixed width so it doesn't go on and on forever, but you will still have limited space.

Comment: your question seems unrelated to landscape, just simply that you can't put that much text in an `l` column which is always one line, use `p{3cm}` or some such. You don't need either `\clearpage` (`landscape` does that) and you don't need `\centering` if you are making the table full width, but don't use `\resizebox` on tables unless as a last resort. Finally use `\linewidth` not `\textwidth` inside `landscape` as `\textwidth` refers to the original portrait page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was preparing an answer exactly on that (the fixed column width).

Comment: @Alenanno I would apprecaite your answer!

Comment: @Alenanno oops sorry just saw your comment...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No problem! You did a nice job. :P

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage,array}% you need array
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum % Text before

\afterpage{%
    %\clearpage%  not needed
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
       % \centering not needed (does nothing here)
        \begin{table}
\centering\footnotesize
\vspace*{-2.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{-1cm}}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
@{\hspace{-1cm}}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Research Studies - Property Market Forecasting Models}}}\\
\textbf{Study Category} 
& \textbf{Author} 
& \textbf{Study Title} 
& \textbf{Description} 
& \textbf{Data} 
& \textbf{Results} \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. 
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. 
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. 
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. 
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum. 
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravidamauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectuset netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverrametus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phaselluseu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congueeu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimrutrum.
\end{tabular}
%} you need to nest afterpage and table properly
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}

\vspace*{-2.5cm}

\end{table}
 %\captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption ??? you added a caption above
 \end{landscape}
 %\clearpage% not needed
}
\lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm... what's going on here? What did you do? Comments in the code, intermixed with the OPs comments?

Comment: @Werner yes comments in code is sometimes the best way of highlighting changes.

Comment: You know me by now. I'll poke and prod for the greater good! :D

Comment: @Werner but in this case with no effect:-)